# Powershell script running fine on Windows 8 but not on Windows 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-8, permission-denied

I am very new to powershell and I'm not sure what I did wrong. It is running fine on my Windows 8 PC but when I send it to someone else (he has Windows 7; created this for him), he gets a not allowed to run scripts error.

Tried with -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned but still no luck.

```
##################
<# CONFIG START #>
##################
#replace the path with your steam path. For example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
$steam_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe"

#You can change it to Ethernet 1 or Ethernet 2 or Ethernet 3 etc depending on which adapter you want to disable.
#If you have custom name for them (you can rename them from control panel), have to use that name.
$adapter_name = "Ethernet 1"

<#
What program to run.
1: Steam Dota 2
2: Steam CS
3: Steam CSS
4: Steam CSGO
5: Custom Program 1
6: Custom Program 2
7: Custom Program 3
#>
$game_id = "5"

<# Custom Program path and arguments#>
$cp1_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\counter-strike source\css.exe"
$cp1_arg = " "

$cp2_path = ""
$cp2_arg = " "

$cp3_path = ""
$cp2_arg = " "

$delay = 20


################
<# CONFIG END #>
################


"Checking admin permissions..."

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    "Administrator permissions required."
    $arguments = '-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "' + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + '"'
#    $arguments
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    Break
}


"Exiting Steam..."
Start-Process -FilePath $steam_path -ArgumentList "-shutdown" -Wait:$true

Start-Sleep -s 2

"Disabling Network Adapter..."
Disable-NetAdapter -Name $adapter_name -Confirm:$false

Start-Sleep -s 5

"Starting Game..."

Switch($game_id)
{

    1
    {
        Start-Process -filepath "steam://rungameid/570"
    }

    2
    {
        Start-Process -filepath "steam://rungameid/10"
    }

    3
    {
        Start-Process -filepath "steam://rungameid/240"
    }

    4
    {
        Start-Process -filepath "steam://rungameid/730"
    }

    5
    {
        Start-Process $cp1_path -ArgumentList $cp1_arg
    }

    6
    {
        Start-Process $cp2_path -ArgumentList $cp2_arg
    }

    7
    {
        Start-Process $cp3_path -ArgumentList $cp3_arg
    }
}

Start-Sleep -s $delay

"Enabling Network Adapter..."
Enable-NetAdapter $adapter_name -Confirm:$false

exit
```

Answer (score 3):

If you sent him the script, then `RemoteSigned` is doing it's job just fine. He got the script remotely (from you) and it is not signed, so it won't be executed.

Tell your friend to navigate to the `ps1` script in Windows Explorer and right click, then choose "Unblock." He will then need to restart the PowerShell instance if it has failed to run the script already since this kind of information is cached by Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you didn't correctly set the execution policy.  Firstly, you have run Powershell as an administrator. To do this, right click on the Powershell icon in the start menu and click on "Run as Administrator". Next you have to run the following command in Powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

You will be prompted to allow the change. Type "Y" and press return.

Finally, try running your script.